# codemirror: detect when last character in line is deleted

Tags: javascript, codemirror

How does my mode "know" when the last character in a line is deleted?

Say, I type something, and my mode object receives calls to `token(stream, state)` as I type. Then if I delete characters one by one, say, by pressing backspace, `token` method gets called every time except for when I delete the last character (in which case `blankLine` is called).

This is not convenient if I build an AST from the tokens. I need to delete the part of my AST that represented the last deleted character. I could use `blankLine` if I could associate it with deletion of the last character, but I cannot find a way.

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A mode doesn't and shouldn't know about changes to the document. It just parses the stream it was given. But you can have other code listen to `"change"` events, and update data structures used by your mode in response to them.